# What is expected behavior of TabControl.ControlRemoved?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The following code:

```
    private void tabControl_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(tabControl.TabCount.ToString());
    }
```

I am assuming should tell me that there are no controls (tabpages) in the TabControl after I close the very last tab. But instead it tells me there is 1.

Is this expected behaviour for TabControl.ControlRemoved, or is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply an order-of-execution problem.  The TabCount property doesn't get updated until *after* the ControlRemoved event fires.  These kind of problems are fairly common with events.

You fix this by executing the code after the event is raised and all processing is completed:

```
    private void tabControl1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            MessageBox.Show(tabControl1.TabCount.ToString());
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you very much @Hans, I will up-vote this answer when I have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

The `ControlRemoved` event is raised/fired before your `TabPage` is actually removed. Your `TabPage` is actually removed only after the `ControlRemoved` event, and of course outside of the `ControlRemoved` event handler. Inside the `ControlRemoved` you can still access to the "removed" `TabPage`. To work-around this, you can try this code instead:

```
private void tabControl_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(tabControl.Controls.OfType<TabPage>().Count().ToString());        
}
```

That means, the `TabPage` is just removed from `Controls` collection, but still in `TabPages` collection.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation and code, @KingKing. I will come back and up-vote this when I have enough rep to do so.